# Datamember name not working when deserializing

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to use `[DataMember(name="")]` to deserialize a CSV where one of the fields in the CSV is a different name to the class property.  In csv it is `Url` and in entity model it is `DomainName`.

This is my class.

```
public class MozApiData
{
    private string _domainName;

    public decimal DA { get; set; }
    public decimal PA { get; set; }
    public decimal MozRank { get; set; }
    public int LinksIn { get; set; }
    public int Equity { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember(Name = "Url")]
    public string DomainName
    {
        get
        {
            return _domainName;
        }
        set
        {
            _domainName = value.ToLower();
        }
    }

}
```

But when I use `csv.FromCsv<List<MozApiData>>()` the `DomainName` property is null.

What did I do wrong with data attribute?

If I set a header mapping it works but wondering why data annotation doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically `[DataMember]` attributes are only valid for use in `[DataContract]` Types, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class MozApiData
{
    private string _domainName;
    [DataMember]
    public decimal DA { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal PA { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal MozRank { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int LinksIn { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Equity { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey]
    [DataMember(Name = "Url")]
    public string DomainName
    {
        get
        {
            return _domainName;
        }
        set
        {
            _domainName = value.ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

But I've just added a change in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/8c7352b658146fbbd00de6821184da6bf61cc2f9) which lets you use `[DataMember(Name = "Url")]` without needing to convert the rest of the Type into a `[DataContract]`.

This change is available from v5.2.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks Mythz that is much appreciated.